# (sed/awk) Extract values from text to csv file - even/odd lines pattern

Tags: csv, sed, awk, row

I need to export some numeric values from a given ASCII text file and export it in a specific formatted csv file. The input file has got the even / odd line pattern:

```
 SCF Done:  E(UHF) =  -216.432419652     A.U. after   12 cycles
 CCSD(T)= -0.21667965032D+03
 SCF Done:  E(UHF) =  -213.594303492     A.U. after   10 cycles
 CCSD(T)= -0.21379841974D+03
 SCF Done:  E(UHF) =  -2.86120139864     A.U. after    6 cycles
 CCSD(T)= -0.29007031339D+01
 and so on
```

I need the odd line value in the 5th column and the even line 2nd column value. They should be printed in a semicolon seperated csv file, with 10 values in each row. So the output should look like

```
-216.432419652;-0.21667965032D+03;-213.594303492;-0.21379841974D+03;-2.86120139864;-0.29007031339D+01; ...linebreak after 5 pairs of values
```

I started with `awk '{print $5}'` and `awk '{print $2}'`, however I was not successful in creating a pattern that just acts on even/odd lines.

A simple way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following script doesn't use a lot of the great power of `awk`, but will do the job for you and is hopefully understandable:

```
NR % 2 { printf "%s;", $5 }
NR % 2 == 0 { printf "%s;", $2 }
NR % 10 == 0 { print "" }
END { print "" }
```

Usage (save the above as `script.awk`):

```
awk -f script.awk input.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It worked perfectly and is easy to understand.

Comment: Always use `printf "%s", $foo` instead of `printf $foo` for any input data as the latter will fail when the input contains formatting chars such as `%s`. Always use `print ""` instead of `printf "\n"` as the former is briefer and uses whatever value ORS is set to while the latter prints the hard-coded value you hope/assume ORS will have.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could work -

```
awk '{x = NF > 3 ? $5 : $2 ; printf("%s;",x)}(NR % 10 == 0){print OFS}' file
     |_____________________|       |________| |___________||_________|
               |                        |           |           |
     This is a `ternary operator`,  Print with `NR` is a    `OFS` is another built-in
  what it does is checks the line  formatting  a built-in    that has a default value of
  for number of fields (`NF`). If    to add    that keeps    `\n`
 the number of fields is more than    a ";"    track of 
 3, we assign $5 value to variable x          number of lines.
      else we assign $2 value                 We are using modulo  
                                             operator to check when
                                             10 lines are crossed.
```

Comment: Sprinkly some whitespace in there: it's free! You don't want your code to become a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: @Alex1167623 Have added information and cleaned up formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Given a file called `data.txt`, try:

```
awk '/SCF/{ printf $5 ";"; } /CCSD/{ printf($2); } NR % 10 == 0 { printf "\n"; }' data.txt
```

Comment: Works also good and do not depent on even / odd lines just on other keywords. thank you

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
 tr -s ' ' ',' <file | paste -sd',\n' | cut -d, -f5,11 | paste -sd',,,,\n'
```